# Django - Add class to individual rows in a ModelChoiceField?

Tags: django, forms

I'm using a model choice field in one of my forms and I would like to add a CSS class to each option based on a value of an attribute of the model.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. You'll have to render the select yourself in the template, iterating over {{ form.field_name.choices }} and generating the class.
2. Create a custom Widget which extends django.forms.widgets.Select and overrides it's render_option() method. For example how it's implemented, see [render_option() in django's source](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/widgets.py#L519). Use the widget in the form (as the field's widget).

   You can see another example of something similar (disabled options in that case) in django snippets: [Allow disabling options in a select widget](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2453/).

IMO the 2nd option is cleaner: it's reusable and no need to mess with the templates.